# How to get all taxonomies of a post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

**How can i get taxonomies of a post type?**

If I have a post type `event` and i need to find out the list of taxonomies that are attached to that post type. How do I find them?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I think I've got it! After looking at couple of functions in the taxonomy.php file in WordPress I have found [the function `get_object_taxonomies();`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_object_taxonomies/) which did the trick :)

Comment: See this for more info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_object_taxonomies

Comment: wow... good to know about get_object_taxonomies().  it just helped me hijack template_redirect

Comment: Hi thankx for this but how to order them by ID instead of NAME?

Comment: easiest way will be just sort them using a `for` or `foreach` loop.

Comment: Yes I am fetching using foreach loop but I am getting order by name
`$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( array( 'post_type' => $post_type ) );
 
foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) :
 
    // Gets every "category" (term) in this taxonomy to get the respective posts
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy ); ?>
 <ul class="specials"><?php 
    foreach( $terms as $term ) : ?>
 
      <li><h2  ><?php echo $term->name; ?></h2>`

Comment: @dh47 I'm late to this thread, but if you're still wondering, I think you'd need to do _two_ `foreach` loops: one to sort them, and one to display them. You could also pass them to `usort` before your `foreach` loop to sort them however you want.

Comment: Heres a oneliner to show all terms for a given `$post` object (any post type): `array_map(function ($taxonomy) use($post) { return wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy); }, get_object_taxonomies($post))` // returns array of all $terms under any taxonomy

Answer (score 9):

[get_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) will do the job.

```
get_categories('taxonomy=taxonomy_name&type=custom_post_type');
```

Comment: (I think if I understood the question right!)

Comment: Thing is i don't have any taxonomy name, that's what i want to find out. I only have the name of the post type. By the post type name i want to find out all the taxonomy that are attached to it. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

Apologies for raising an old post, but I came across this problem while looking for an answer for my use case.

I wanted to retrieve all available taxonomies for a post type, and also retrieve all available terms per taxonomy.

Thank you to Nick B for setting me in the right direction with his answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/357448/198353

```
// get a list of available taxonomies for a post type
$taxonomies = get_taxonomies(['object_type' => ['your_post_type']]);

$taxonomyTerms = [];

// loop over your taxonomies
foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy)
{
  // retrieve all available terms, including those not yet used
  $terms    = get_terms(['taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 'hide_empty' => false]);

  // make sure $terms is an array, as it can be an int (count) or a WP_Error
  $hasTerms = is_array($terms) && $terms;

  if($hasTerms)
  {
    $taxonomyTerms[$taxonomy] = $terms;        
  }
}
```

Comment: This crashes my website

Comment: In what sense does this code snippet crash your website? Unless you have an astronomical amount of taxonomies and terms, it's unlikely to be the fault of this snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried anything? something like this?

```
<?php 

$args=array(
  'object_type' => array('event') 
); 

$output = 'names'; // or objects
$operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'
$taxonomies=get_taxonomies($args,$output,$operator); 
if  ($taxonomies) {
  foreach ($taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {
    echo '<p>'. $taxonomy. '</p>';
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Looked at `get_taxonomies();` function on codex but it has very poor documentation and was no idea how i can pass the post types.

Comment: Sorry, this code is returning all registered taxonomies in wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

```
$taxonomies = get_taxonomies( [ 'object_type' => [ 'custom_post_type' ] ] );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `get_object_taxonomies` (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_object_taxonomies/), which takes either the name of your custom post type or a post object as the parameter:

```
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies('custom_post_type');
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies($custom_post_object);
```

`get_taxonomies()` won't return any taxonomies that are used by multiple post types (https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/27918).

Answer (score 1):

```
get_post_taxonomies()
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_taxonomies/

This worked for me.

Comment: This function retrieves all taxonomy names **for the given post**, which is not what OP wants, but this is what I was actually looking for, thanks.