# Get current term in single.php

Tags: terms

I have a custom post type (dibujos) and 4 custom taxonomy.

I would like to get term name in a current post.

The probleme is, how to To display the name of the taxonomy, no matter what taxonomy is.

The code is:

```
<?php   // Get terms for post
 $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'my-taxonomy' );
 // Loop over each item since it's an array
 if ( $terms != null ){
 foreach( $terms as $term ) {
 // Print the name method from $term which is an OBJECT
 print $term->name ;
 // Get rid of the other data stored in the object, since it's not needed
 unset($term);
} } ?>
```

Thks!

Comment: I don't really understand this - you know the name of your taxonomy - you're specifying it in the `get_the_terms()` call. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Hi, I have 4 different taxonomy. How to know the taxonomy in the current post?

Comment: I think you need to reframe the question. The code sample you've picked specifically chooses terms from a single taxonomy. Do you want to get all terms from all taxonomies?

Comment: No, i need the current term, not all terms. THKS

Comment: Your question makes no sense - please edit it to be very clear whether you want to know the name of the taxonomy or the term.

Comment: The question is a bit missleading because it asks for a term, instead its related to the taxonomy name. this has been answered here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20574/how-to-get-all-taxonomies-of-a-post-type

but this question here does appear, when you search for "wordpress terms single.php" so i also was searching wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `wp_get_object_terms($object_ids, $taxonomies, $args)` to get all terms from a defined set of taxonomies for an object

The `$taxonomies` parameter can be an array of taxonomy names.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms

Answer (score 0):

> Hi, I have 4 different taxonomy. How to know the taxonomy in the current post?

Nope, you cannot get the taxonomy name on single.php.
What are you trying to achieve with this? You probably need to look at a problem from a different angle.

Comment: Hi, I try to get a navigation path (like a breadcrumbs). For example: If i'm looking for a house i would like to put a link to see all houses. I try with $wp_query->queried_object->name but nothing happend.

Answer (score 0):

Opsss Sorry I made a mess.

Put this code by each taxonomy

```
<?php if( false != get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'my-taxonomy' ) ) {
     echo '<li>'.(__('Ver más:')) . get_the_term_list($post->ID,'my-taxonomy', ' ', ' ', '' ).'</li>'; }
 ?>
```